# SignalR + passing custom object from server to client not working

Tags: c#, signalr

I am trying to pass a custom object from self hosted signalr hub server to all the clients, the method in client side not getting invoked .But if the same custom class object is passed from client to server works fine, meaning it invokes the server method.

below is the sample code :

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public void Send(DataContract message)
    {
        //below call not reaching to client while passing custom obj
        Clients.All.SendMessage(message);  
        //below string passing works - means invokes client method
        Clients.All.SendMsg("test");         
    }       
}
```

custom class defined in both client and server project via dll:

```
public class DataContract
{
    public string Name
    {
        get;set;
    }

    public int Id
    {
        get;set;
    }
}
```

client side method:

```
public class SignalRClient
{
    HubConnection hubConnection = null;
    IHubProxy chat;       

    public SignalRClient()
    {
        hubConnection = new HubConnection("https://localhost/");
        chat = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("ChatHub");
    }
    public void StartConnection()
    {
        if (hubConnection != null)
        {
            hubConnection.Start().Wait();
        }           

        chat.On<DataContract>("SendMessage", (stock) => 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("name {0} id {1}", stock.Name, stock.Id.ToString());
            });

          chat.On<string>("SendMsg", (message) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(message);
        });
     }

    public void SendMessage(DataContract dd)
    {
          dd.Name = "test";
          chat.Invoke("Send", dd).Wait();
    }

    public void SendMessage(string msg)
    {
          chat.Invoke("SendMsg", "Console app", msg).Wait();
    }
}
```

//program.cs

```
main()
{
     SignalRClient client = new SignalRClient();
     client.StartConnection();

     string msg = null;
     while ((msg = Console.ReadLine()) != null)
     {
          DataContract dd = new DataContract { Name = "arun", Id = 9 };  
          //below calls reaches to server both string type and custome obj                     
          client.SendMessage(dd);  
          client.SendMessage("client");           
     }
}
```

Any clue on why when calling from server (i.e  Clients.All.SendMessage(message); ) not invoking client method when param is custom object.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you verified that it works with just String and/or Int as parameters? The custom type gets serialized using the JSON serializer, but there's nothing in your DataContract class that should be causing a problem-

Comment: this link helped to solve : simple syntax issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13749897/error-sending-object-to-net-signalr-client

Comment: What was the issue? I have the same problem.